# Requested URL /apex/apex_admin failed

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I installed Oracle application express 11.2 on Oracle Linux 6.9 with Oracle Database 11g. When I run localhost on browser then it gives error "The requested URL /apex/apex_admin was not found on this server"

I checked through command:

```
SELECT VERSION, STATUS, COMP_ID FROM DBA_REGISTRY WHERE COMP_ID='APEX';
```

Version column "Blank"

Status column = Loading

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: Looks like a wrong URL. How exactly did you try to access the admin page? I'm on Windows; nonetheless, it looks like this: `http://my_server_name:8084/apex/apex_admin`

Comment: @Littlefoot  http://localhost:8080/apex/apex_admin

Comment: Your port is 8080. Check whether it is correct: `select dbms_xdb.gethttpport from dual;`